How to derive phase kickback probabilities
I don't get how the prob on the left is equal to the probability on the right. I calculate the modulus and square it and I get $\cos(2\pi\theta)/2$ not $\cos^2(\pi\theta)$.
${\rm Prob}(1+e^{2\pi i\theta})/2 = \cos^2(\pi\theta)$

Hello. I posted an answer below under a few assumptions. First, I assumed that by $\text{P}((1+e^{2\pi i \phi})/2)$ you actually mean the probability of measuring state $|0\rangle$ after performing phase kick-back on a controlled unitary with eigenvalue $e^{2\pi i \phi}$. Second, the $1/2$ on the left-hand side should be part of the prob amplitude of state $|0\rangle$; you seem to have it outside of the norm-squared calculation.

The norm-squared of a complex $a \in \mathbb{C}$ number is calculated by multiplying that number with it's complex conjugate. So, for:
$$ a = \frac{1 + e^{2 \pi i \phi}}{2}, $$
you get:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|a|^2 &= a a^*
\\
\\
|a|^2 &=\frac{\left(1 + e^{2 \pi i \phi} \right)}{2}\frac{\left(1 + e^{-2 \pi i \phi} \right)}{2}
\\
\\
|a|^2 &= \frac{1 + e^{-2 \pi i \phi} + e^{2 \pi i \phi} + e^{2 \pi i \phi} e^{-2 \pi i \phi}}{4}
\\
\\
|a|^2 &= \frac{2 + 2\cos(2\pi\phi)}{4}
\\
\\
|a|^2 &= \frac{4 \cos^2(\pi\phi)}{4}
\\
\\
|a|^2 &= cos^2(\pi\phi)
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore,
$$\big|\frac{1 + e^{2 \pi i \phi}}{2}\big|^2 = cos^2(\pi\phi)$$

Thanks, I appreciate it. I got lost at step 4. Can you share the trigonometric identity to go from step 4 to step 5?

Absolutely: $\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2x))$, therefore: $4 \cos^2(x) = \frac{4}{2}(1 + \cos(2x)) = 2 + 2 \cos(2x)$

Does that particular identity have a name?

Power-reduction identity, but you can derive it from the angle addition formula for the cosine by making both angles equal.

Thanks man, I appreciate it.

No prob! Make sure to marked your question as “answered” if you’re satisfied with the response
